# OpenCV - Rectangle Detection in a image with reflections

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to create an algorithm for detecting a rectangle in OpenCV collected from a camera of a robot. So naturally, I get a fair amount of variability due to the robot moving. Using this code

```
    def original_settings(img):
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #cv.imshow("Gray", gray)
    blur = cv.medianBlur(gray,5)
    #cv.imshow("Blur", blur)
    sharpen = cv.filter2D(blur, -1, sharpen_kernel)
    #cv.imshow("Sharpen", sharpen)
    return sharpen

    def find_square(img):
    thresh = cv.threshold(img, 160, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
    #cv.imshow("Threshhold", thresh)
    kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
    close = cv.morphologyEx(thresh, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
    #cv.imshow("Morphology Search", close)
    close = cv.bitwise_not(close)
    #cv.imshow("Invert Search", close)
    cnts = cv.findContours(close, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

    min_area = 3500
    max_area = 5000
    image_number = 0
    for c in cnts:
        area = cv.contourArea(c)
        #print(area)
        if area > min_area and area < max_area:
            x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(c)
            cv.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36, 255, 12), 2)
            print("Width: {}, Height: {}, x: {}, y: {}".format(w,h,x,y))
            image_number += 1
            #print((x, y))
            return True
    return False

    find_square(original_settings(image))
```

I am largely successful with my images. However, I have one situation that I can't quite pinpoint. When I process this

[image]

My algorithm catches the whole thing, which appears to have an extra bit of rectangle due to `reflectiog`. Instead of just the larger rectangle, like this

[image: this].

How can I get OpenCV to ignore this extra chunk of rectangle?

Comment: Look at your threshold image. One threshold value (160) may not work for all your images. Have you tried Otsu thresholding?

Comment: I found using Otsu thresholding it would sometimes decide to use the wrong part of some of my images. If my algorithm fails to find a rectangle at all I attempt to brighten or darken the image in preprocessing. So far this has worked 98% of the time. The issue with this image is the reflection is about the same brightness as the actual flag